# Preload relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I want that every time I instantiate a `User` in my application from my `UsersController`, it comes with the relationships that it has created. I mead, for example a `User` `belongsTo` a `Person` and a `User` `hasMany` `Form`. 
This is the way I handle my object right now:

```
public function show( User $user ){
    $user->person;
    $user->forms;
    return view( 'admin.show', compact( 'user' ) );
}
```

But I don't think, that is a correct way to do it. It would be nice if I could get rid of `$user->person;` and `$user->forms;`

How can I accomplish it?

Comment: But you don't need to eager loading anything if accessing the data in server time... Sometimes people use "load" when they don't actually need it.

Comment: @Amarnasan is correct, you should not need to load it as long as the relation exists. Just access it with $user->the_relation in your model/blade

Comment: It is a shame, that you didn't post this as an answer, because this, combined with the answer by Shridhar Sharma, explained a lot to me. The correct way to do what I was asking was to use load, but it was not necessary, since I could still use Eloquent inside my views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do so by using eager loading concept;

```
public function show( User $user ){
    $user->load(['person','forms']);
    return view( 'admin.show', compact( 'user' ) );
}
```

Comment: if you use the person or form data (almost) always, than you should consider defining them as eager relations:
    `Class MyModel extends Model {
        protected $with = ['person', 'forms'];
    }`

Comment: Actually your answer was very helpful. I was thinking that when in a view, I was not allowed to use eloquent relationships and that everything passed to the view remained static. Thanks a lot.